# Is there way to print specific report from unit test function in Odoo?

Tags: python, report, odoo, python-unittest

Please make changes in below code to print report in specific folder

def test_report_rent(self):

```
    data = self.env['rentalagreement'].search([('id','=',4)])
    pdf = self.request.env['ir.actions.report'].sudo().get_pdf([data], 'building_management.report_building_agreement_my', data=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def test_data(self):
        for i in self.rent:
            print(i.id,i.state)
            i.action_rentalagreement_done()
            self.assertEqual(i.state,'done','successful')
            self.assertNotEqual(i.state,'draft','failed')
        from_date = fields.Date.to_string(fields.Date.add(fields.Date.today(), days=-22))
        to_date = fields.Date.to_string(fields.Date.add(fields.Date.today(), days=5))
        data = self.env['rentalagreement'].search([('agreement_date','>=',from_date),('agreement_date','<=',to_date),('building_id','=',5)])
        print(data)
        print(self.env.ref('building_management.report_building_agreement_my').report_action(docids=data))
        return self.env.ref('building_management.report_building_agreement_my').report_action(docids=data)
```

Comment: what does this mean? Where are you returning report? Where it will be stored? On server?

return self.env.ref('building_management.report_building_agreement_my').report_action(docids=data)

Answer (score 0):

```
 def test_data(self):
  
    
    temp = self.env['ir.attachment'].search([])
    for i in temp:
        if i.name == 'dharmik.pdf':
            print(i.name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - a short explanation provided with a code-snippet can help explain the code.